# Why can't edit-flagging use heuristics to determine if a change was substantial

Tags: feature-request, edits, community-wiki

Quite often I write a question or answer on SO, then re-read it and notice a typo; so I fix that.  Then later I am looking it over again and another typo pops out at me; so I fix that - doing this it's very easy to push the edits up close to the limit before it becomes community wiki.

But, surely minor corrective edits by anyone and any number of edits by any one person should not count toward making something CW; only non-trivial edits by some number, say 10, of different people should trigger CW from editing.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of auto-CW is to discourage the use of editing solely for the purpose of "bumping" a question (making it appear on the front page).

The purpose of bumping is to give some attention to updated posts.

Of course, minor changes wouldn't need the attention, and therefore wouldn't need to be bumped...

...but good luck coming up with an algorithm that'll differentiate between simple typo correction and [subtly-malicious changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/33089/list#rev-arrow-956c1d60-a97a-4156-86ac-3aa930f946a4).

Comment: A minor edit is any that involves less than *some small number* of consecutive characters, no super algorithm required.  And a minor change should not be bumped. The comments regarding malicious changes are a non-sequitur.

Comment: That *comment* was a non sequitur. Explain yourself, Monkey!

Comment: I meant the *edits illustrating* malicious changes...

Answer (score 1):

Have you really pushed a post over to CW by editing it so much? You need to edit it 10 times for this to happen, where each edit is in its own window (5 minutes for the initial posting, 2 minutes for every edit thereafter).

Do you take advantage of the preview window so as to not submit until you are satisfied with your edit?  I usually only have two or three edits register when I am posting, even for extensively thought-out posts involving a lot of code and details; I also use the Firefox plugin "[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/el/firefox/addon/4125)", so I can use my editor of choice (Vim) for writing my post, which really helps out when writing code on the fly.

Comment: I've come damn close on complex answers.  Esp. when responding to comments, where you add some more detail.  Given 5 comments that prompt for more detail, it's not hard to have 5 additional edits that push it over the limit.  All over the space of several hours.

Comment: And the problem with previewing is your brain's auto-correct feature; where it sees what it expects and not what's actually there.

Comment: Yes, I have several times pushed a question or answer over the limit by making minor corrections and additions.